# StreamingOutput in jax-rs usecases?

Tags: jax-rs

JAX-RS provides StreamingOutput interface that we can implement to do raw streaming of our response bodies.

```
public interface StreamingOutput {
    void write(OutputStream output)
}
```

I am not sure as to why they go about building an interface to expose the response outputstream. Why not just inject an OutputStream directly and we can simply write on to it!!

Answer (score 7):

In the book [RESTful Java with JAX-RS 2.0](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wzkYAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=Chapter+6.+JAX-RS+Content+Handlers&source=bl&ots=dmxF1pWAnA&sig=KcP8_pNZ5JElkDLF_umkP5HliQw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9_r75k5bOAhVLBywKHcsKBLYQ6AEILzAD#v=onepage&q=Chapter%206.%20JAX-RS%20Content%20Handlers&f=false) written by Bill Burk (one of RESTEasy authors), you will find a good explanation about `StreamingOutput`.

The same question you asked is answered by the author:

> `StreamingOutput` is a simple callback interface that you implement when you want to do raw streaming of response bodies [...]
>
> You allocate implemented instances of this interface and return them from your JAX-RS resource methods. When the JAX-RS runtime is ready to write the response body of the message, the `write()` method is invoked on the `StreamingOutput` instance. [...]
>
> You may be asking yourself, **“Why not just inject an `OutputStream` directly? Why have a callback object to do streaming output?”** That’s a good question! The reason for having a callback object is that it gives the JAX-RS implementation freedom to handle output however it wants. For performance reasons, it may sometimes be beneficial for the JAX-RS implementation to use a different thread other than the calling thread to output responses. More importantly, many JAX-RS implementations have an interceptor model that abstracts things out like automatic GZIP encoding or response caching. Streaming directly can usually bypass these architectural constructs. Finally, the Servlet 3.0 specification has introduced the idea of asynchronous responses. The callback model fits in very nicely with the idea of asynchronous HTTP within the Servlet 3.0 specification.

And the `StreamingOutput` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/StreamingOutput.html) states the following:

> This is a lightweight alternative to a [MessageBodyWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html).